# Default math fonts

Tags: fonts

If I call `mathptmx`, the following are carried out:

```
\def\rmdefault{ptm}
\DeclareSymbolFont{operators}   {OT1}{ztmcm}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{letters}     {OML}{ztmcm}{m}{it}
\DeclareSymbolFont{symbols}     {OMS}{ztmcm}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{largesymbols}{OMX}{ztmcm}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{bold}        {OT1}{ptm}{bx}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{italic}      {OT1}{ptm}{m}{it}
\@ifundefined{mathbf}{}{\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathbf}{OT1}{ptm}{bx}{n}}
\@ifundefined{mathit}{}{\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathit}{OT1}{ptm}{m}{it}}
```

My question is: what are the defaults, i.e. what would these fonts be if I didn't call `mathptmx`? I guess `\rmdefault` would be `cmr` for Computer Modern, but the others? Also, I know `\mathcal` is redefined in `mathptmx`, since the font changes, but I cannot find the code redefining it. Which is that code? And again, what is the default? And what about `\mathfrak`? Does it get changed too?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The defaults in the format are from `fontmath.ltx`

```
\DeclareSymbolFont{operators}   {OT1}{cmr} {m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{letters}     {OML}{cmm} {m}{it}
\DeclareSymbolFont{symbols}     {OMS}{cmsy}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{largesymbols}{OMX}{cmex}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{operators}{bold}{OT1}{cmr} {bx}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{letters}  {bold}{OML}{cmm} {b}{it}
\SetSymbolFont{symbols}  {bold}{OMS}{cmsy}{b}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet{\mathrm}    {operators}
\DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet{\mathnormal}{letters}
\DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet{\mathcal}   {symbols}
\DeclareMathAlphabet      {\mathbf}{OT1}{cmr}{bx}{n}
\DeclareMathAlphabet      {\mathsf}{OT1}{cmss}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathAlphabet      {\mathit}{OT1}{cmr}{m}{it}
\DeclareMathAlphabet      {\mathtt}{OT1}{cmtt}{m}{n}
```

Where you see `\mathcal` doesn't really get defined by the mathptm package it's just that it picks up the `symbol` font `OMS` encoding having calligraphic letters in the uppercase slots.

Comment: And "the culprit" for `\mathfrak` is `amsfonts` with its `\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathfrak}{U}{euf}{m}{n} \SetMathAlphabet{\mathfrak}{bold}{U}{euf}{b}{n}`. Which means `mathptmx` is unlikely to affect it.