# Using MathTimePro 2 without changing math font

Tags: math-mode, unicode-math, italic

I am using MathTimePro2 especially for better looking over-/underbrackets `\undercbrace` and `\overcbrace`.

Of course mtpro2 is a font package and it somehow changes the default math style: it is no more the usual italic style. The author of mtpro2 suggests to use Times with the package, but that's not what I want.

- I would simply like to revert to this default behaviour: `$italic variables$`
- `\mathit{italic vars}` does the job, but that's very uncomfortable.

I already tried to understand [this similar question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/159973/french-math-style-with-default-font), although not beeing related to mt2pro. It requires loading `unicode-math` which somehow interferes with mtpro2. I took

```
\usepackage[math-style=TeX]{unicode-math}
```

from the documentation. Setting the math-style to TeX-style is what I wish (meaning *variables italic* and greek alphabet upright).

**Update**

A fast solution I found 10 minutes later:

Calling the second line

```
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro 2}
\DeclareSymbolFont{letters}     {OML}{cmm} {m}{it}
```

right after loading the package seems to do what I wanted to. Got the command from [another question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/236965/default-math-fonts). *Sadly some brackets and other stuff (at least large greek like `\Lambda`) now seem to be messed up:*

[image: Parantheses <code>(</code> and <code>)</code>]

[image: Missing <code>Lambda</code>]

Comment: `mtpro2` takes its parentheses `(` and `)` from its fonts (with its own encoding `LMP1`). The default Computer Modern math setup takes its parentheses directly from text font. These two encodings are incompatible.

Comment: So, in order ti get around the problem: Is there any workaround to exclusively use the `mtpro2` extra symbols provided? Or to somehow fix the parantheses issue? Thanks!